# WebSphere DataSource Connection Failing

Tags: java, database-connection, datasource, websphere-8

I'm using WebSphere 8.5.5 and have a DataSource created. When I click "Test Connection" from the "Data Sources" page the test is successful! When the application is started though, I get an error message and lengthy stack trace. I have the identical application code and DS setup running fine in another WebSphere instance. Here's the message and a partial stack trace.

```
[10/18/19 10:37:54:465 EDT] 00000081 SystemOut     O 2019-10-18 10:37:54,465 INFO o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper [WebContainer : 3] HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: icegate
    ...]

[10/18/19 10:37:55:650 EDT] 00000081 SystemOut     O 2019-10-18 10:37:55,649 WARN o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator [WebContainer : 3] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
[10/18/19 10:37:55:658 EDT] 00000081 SystemOut     O 2019-10-18 10:37:55,657 INFO o.h.d.Dialect [WebContainer : 3] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
[10/18/19 10:37:55:660 EDT] 00000081 SystemOut     O 2019-10-18 10:37:55,659 INFO o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl [WebContainer : 3] HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
[10/18/19 10:37:57:465 EDT] 00000081 SystemOut     O 2019-10-18 10:37:57,430 ERROR o.h.h.s.i.IdTableHelper [WebContainer : 3] Unable obtain JDBC Connection
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
```

Comment: Hmm - `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied` - is it not clear enough? Either your component alias is different from container, or you are overriding db configuration in your application for example in hibernate config. In summary username/password is not correct for that database.

Comment: It turns out the problem was that the JVM had to be restarted for the application to pick up the changes. Just restarting the application wasn't enough.